# Executing VBA function from current workbook in cell formula get error #name (#nom for French version)

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I meet a problem which is probably very simple when I use a VBA function into a formula of a cell, I get the cell content "#NAME" (not found function ? while a macro using the function (for test) is executed normally (displays the wished content for the cell, the returned value by the function, which extracts the filename from a fullpath).

*context :*

I had by the past (more than 12 years ago) developed, may be 50,000, VBA instructions, using office2003.
Today I have to develop again some macros with Office365. So I have forgotten a lot since this time and some features can have changed which can become tricking (I need to read again my old soft to recall all my knowledge, but I have no access to for now)

***The problem***

- I get the error "#name" when I use a function created into VBA
  associated to the current workbook. No explanation, no help, I tried to
  find something during several hours and I found nothing.

  - I have developed too for testing (see code) a "sub" which calls the function, and his execution is successful, but...
  - I cannot run the function from the formula of any cell.
  - I have tested the security parameters of macro and fully unlocked the execution temporarily, and too declare the local directory as confident area.

Note : this code is detailed as an example

***The code***

```
Public Function FNameOf(CellPointed As Range)

Dim CurCell As Range
Dim Text1 As String
Dim Text2 As String

    Set CurCell = CellPointed

    Text1 = CurCell.Value
    Text2 = Mid$(Text1, InStrRev(Text1, "\") + 1, Len(Text1))

    FNameOf = Text2
End Function

Sub DispFileName2()
Dim style, disp, titre
Dim Cursel As Range
    'Cursel = ActiveCell

    disp = FNameOf(ActiveCell)
    style = vbOKOnly
    titre = "Nom du fichier extrait du texte (fullpath) de la cellule courante"

    MsgBox disp, style, titre

End Sub
```

If I submit the macro DispFileName2 if get the message with the file name extracted from the path which is the content of the current cell

If I set the formule of a cell :

```
=FNameOf(AnotherCell) 'which contains a fullpath to a file
```

I get always the error  "#NOM" (in French version) or, I think so, "#NAME" (in english Version) as if the function name (ref) was unknown from the workbook (the code is not reached, a stop is set on the first instruction)

What can be the reason ?

Comment: Your code works well with Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Please place your user defined function *somewhere in a module* (neither in "ThisWorkbook" nor in the individual worksheet's code, e. g. "Feuil1").
You should add the result declaration `As String` also.
I understood the example is for reference only, but you may shorten it:

```
Public Function FNameOf(CellPointed As Range) As String
    FNameOf = Mid(CellPointed.Value, InStrRev(CellPointed.Value, "\") + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: `, Len(Text1)` is unnecessary for vba mid. If the third argument is omitted, the length of the original string is defaulted. So `FNameOf = Mid$(Text1, InStrRev(Text1, "\") + 1)`.

Comment: Could also be `FNameOf = split(Text1, "\")(ubound(split(Text1, "\")))`

Comment: Second is interesting, but harder to understand and results in an error, if range `CellPointed` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I had not seen the answers because I miss to update the tab before going to answer to my own question...

Comment: Yes I may shorten the code but it was only for example as I told, thanks for the shorten code.
I am going to develop a little lib to manage fields contents into thunderbird context (folder of mails, files, accounts ... to get a clear view of accounts and all parameters and check for errors)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution while reading in more details previous edited threads in several tabs.
It is explained into a remark of : thread 12351339

The text is :

> Microsoft Excel Objects such as 'Sheet1' or 'ThisWorkbook' are
>   classes. I don't believe you can access Functions which you put in
>   these classes through a cell. You could access them in VBA e.g.
>   ThisWorkbook.Square2() but it's recommended to put all UDF's into as
>   standard module and not a worksheet module. – Eddie Sep 28 '17 at
>   13:49

**By default the creation panel defines code associated to current worksheet, then the function is not visible for the worksheet while the sub is a macro of the worksheet.**

I have created a module and the function has run immediately.

Best regards

Trebly

Note : I never met this problem of visibility before because the developments where since the beginning concerning VBA user classes and modules combining multiple Excel workbooks and Word and a Mail manager activeX and so on...

I keep the subject because of the explanations, code and keywords may be to find more easily the solution for anybody else.